# Manga where the female lead is part of a crime family in a fantasy medieval world, and part of the yakuza in her previous life

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I know that the female lead has red hair, while her fiancé has black hair. Despite being part of a crime family, because of how she was taught by her grandfather in her previous life, she wishes to have a normal, kind background lifestyle where she’s good. She also attends an academy with her fiancé having the magical ability of commanding others against their wishes, with him being cold/sadistic and she’s the daughter of one of the four dukedoms.

Other than that, I don’t really remember much else.

Comment: Is the answer below correct? If it is, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grey check mark on the left side of the answer. It should turn green if you've done it correctly, and you'll gain +2 reputation. Only do so if the answer is correct, of course. If it's incorrect, please leave a comment stating that, so that we know to keep looking.

Comment: By the way, somebody upvoted this answer earlier today. I don't know if that was you or not, but if it was, upvoting an answer isn't the same thing as marking it as accepted. The acceptance button is the check mark below the upvote and downvote buttons. Only the author of a question can mark an answer to that question as accepted, and unless they do so, or state that an answer is correct with a comment, then a question will not officially be judged to have been solved.

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[Akutou Ikka no Mana Musume, Tensei Saki mo Otome Game no Gokudou Reijou deshita. Saijoukyuu Rank no Akuyaku-sama, Sono Dekiai wa Fuyou desu!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/akutou-ikka-no-mana-musume-tensei-saki-mo-otome-game-no-gokudou-reijou-deshita-saijoukyuu-rank-no-akuyaku-sama-sono-dekiai-wa-fuyou-desu)***...?

> A girl who grew up as the granddaughter of a gangster family was reincarnated in a otome game, where the early modern mafia makes a secret move. She was the beloved daughter of the five major families that support the monarchy from behind the scenes! A dangerous love game between a former gangster's granddaughter and a villainous fiancé begins!
>
> [image: Promotional art for "Akutou Ikka no Mana Musume, Tensei Saki mo Otome Game no Gokudou Reijou deshita. Saijoukyuu Rank no Akuyaku-sama, Sono Dekiai wa Fuyou desu!."]

In her previous life, the main character's parents died when she was five years old and she was subsequently raised by her grandfather, a yakuza crime boss. He's portrayed as a loving grandfather with an honourable nature, but she didn't enjoy growing up surrounded by black-suited bodyguards, and yearned for a normal, peaceful life.

She's later killed by an assassin and wakes up as Francesca Anna-Leah Calvino, the red-haired heroine of a historical fantasy game she was playing before she died. Francesca is the daughter of the head of one of five powerful families who control the underworld to support the king in this world, mirroring her situation in her previous life.

She's engaged to Lord Leonardo Valentino Aldini, who has black hair and is the head of one of the other four powerful families. Leonardo is the main villain of the game, and is portrayed as being cold and sadistic. They attend a Royal Academy together and have special 'skills,' one of Leonardo's skills being the ability to forcibly restrict people's movements.